# SQL Server unique records in row_number() range of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT      
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [rownum],
        UserID, wfoKey 
    FROM
        tbl_user_statistics2 Where (wfoKey = '4b1fbf7aa7')
) T
WHERE 
rownum BETWEEN (@opt_start) AND (@opt_end)
```

The above query works and pulls all UserID's from rows 1 (opt_start) to 10,000 (opt_end).  In that data set those UserID's are duplicated.  I would like to now pull out the unique UserID's for the records in that range of rows (1 to 10,000). The user can select any range so they could pick 10,0000 to 20,0000 so the query should get the unique UserID's in that range and so on. I don't need the rownum in the result.

Sample data:

```
1   dced6f0d-3a67-456d78cb7-fb73c8db0c13    4b1fbf7aa7
2   dced6f0d-3a67-456d78cb7-fb73c8db0c13    4b1fbf7aa7
3   6360f485-4f4d-4c9a98b0e-74fea312a25d    4b1fbf7aa7
4   6360f485-4f4d-4c9a98b0e-74fea312a25d    4b1fbf7aa7
```

The result would be:

```
dced6f0d-3a67-456d78cb7-fb73c8db0c13    4b1fbf7aa7
6360f485-4f4d-4c9a98b0e-74fea312a25d    4b1fbf7aa7
```

Not sure how to proceed or perhaps there is a better way than row_number() over. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by taking your existing query and turning it into an in-line view (`T2`) and then querying the distinct records from it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, wfoKey FROM
(SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT      
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [rownum],
        UserID, wfoKey 
    FROM
        tbl_user_statistics2 Where (wfoKey = '4b1fbf7aa7')
) T
WHERE 
rownum BETWEEN (@opt_start) AND (@opt_end)) T2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE1
AS
 (
 SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY wfoKey)
 FROM tbl_user_statistics2 
 Where wfoKey = '4b1fbf7aa7'
 ),
 CTE2
 AS
 (
  SELECT ID, UserID, wfoKey 
       , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wfoKey)
  FROM CTE1 
  WHERE rn = 1 
  )
SELECT ID, UserID, wfoKey 
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@opt_start) AND (@opt_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a piece called partition by userID

```
    ;with cte as(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (
        SELECT      
            row_number() OVER (partition by USerID ORDER BY ID) AS [rownum],
            UserID, wfoKey 
        FROM
            tbl_user_statistics2 Where (wfoKey = '4b1fbf7aa7')
    ) T
    WHERE 
    rownum BETWEEN (@opt_start) AND (@opt_end) 
    )

    Select * from cte
    where rownum =1
```